# I don't understand the proof that $ \| \overline{u} \|_{W^{1,p}(B)} \leq C \| u \|_{W^{1,p}(B^+)}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

This is from Evan's PDE's Extension Theorem (Theorem 1 in Section 5.4.) [One can find a proof like this here](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Etan/Sobolev%20Space/5.4.pdf). I have an old edition of the book so I don't think my page is going to work for anyone here.

Here are the relevant information

Define

$$\overline{u}(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
u(x) & x \in B^+ \\ 
 -3u(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},-x_n) + 4u(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},-x_n/2)& x \in B^-
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $B$ is an open ball with centre $x^0$ and radius $r$ and

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
B^+ := B \cap \{x_n \geq 0\}  \subset \overline{U}
\\ 
B^- := B \cap \{x_n \leq 0\} \subset R^n -\overline{U}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $U$ is a bounded (open) set.

$W^{1,p}(U)$ is the Sobolev space of $U$.

**Q1**: In the pdf I linked (**Step 4**), why is $\| \overline{u} \|_{W^{1,p} (B) } =\|-3u(...,-x_n) + 4u(...,-x_n/2) \|_{W^{1,p} (B) }$? Isn't the quantity $-3u(...,-x_n) + 4u(...,-x_n/2)$ only defined on the lower half of the ball?

> [image]

**Q2:** What exactly is $\| \overline{u} \|_{W^{1,p} (B) }?$ Is it defined as

$$\int_B \| \overline{u} \|^p + \int_B \|D\overline{u} \|$$?

And is that further equal to

$$\int_B \| \overline{u} \|^p = \int_{x_n = 0}  \| \overline{u} \|^p + \int_{B^{+}} \| u \|^p +  \int_{B^{-}} \| -3u + 4u \|^p$$

and similarly for $\int_B \|D\overline{u} \|.$

**Q3**: Lastly I just don't quite understand the last estimation involving $B \cap \{x_n < r\}$

Answer (score 3):

re:Q2, Evans defines $$\|f\|_{W^{1,p}(B)}^p :=\sum_{0\le\alpha\le 1}\|D^\alpha f\|_{L^p(B)}^p= \sum_{0\le\alpha\le 1}\int |D^\alpha f(x)|^p \ dx.$$ Note $\|f\|_X$ is usually reserved for a function norm; the Euclidean norm / absolute value is written $|x|$.

Note that it is different from
\begin{align} \| f\|_{L^p(B)}^p+\|D f\|_{L^p(B)}^p
&= \int_B | f(x)|^p \ dx + \int_B | Df(x)|^p \ dx \\
&= \int_B | f(x)|^p \ dx +\int_B \left(\sum_{|\alpha|=1}| D^\alpha f(x)|^2\right)^{p/2} \ dx ,\end{align}
but they define equivalent norms. What you wrote with $\int |Du| dx$ is NOT equivalent because its missing a $p$. Unless $p=1$.

So re:Q1, you have indeed found a typo; $u$ is only defined on the upper ball. In fact there are more typos, the notes write $\alpha<1$ but this means $\alpha=0$. And the calculation involves $|2^{-p}v|^p$ which is $2^{-p^2}|v|^p$? It may be better to read Evans (sorry Chee Han!). Perhaps what they meant to write was
$$ \|\bar u\|_{W^{1,p}(B^-)} = \|{-3} u(\dots,-x_n)+4 u(\dots,-x_n/2)\|_{W^{1,p}(B^-)}.$$
In order to use that $\|\bar u\|_{W^{1,p}(B^-)} + \|\bar u\|_{W^{1,p}(B^+)} =  \|\bar u\|_{W^{1,p}(B)} $, for which we first need weak differentiability, one uses some continuity arguments (which you have because of the way the function was extended to the lower ball; this is the earlier part of the proof in Evans.)

Back to Q2, specialising to $f=\overline u$:

$$\int_B | \overline{u} |^pdx =  \int_{B^{+}} | u |^p dx+  \int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u(x',-x_n) + 4u(x',-x_n/2) |^p dx' dx_n.$$
We used that $B=B^+\cup B^-$ up to a $\mathbb R^n$-Lebesgue null set (a subset of $\{x:x_n=0\}$).
Note that the last term $\int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u(x',-x_n) + 4u(x',-x_n/2) |^p dx' dx_n$ is different from
$$ \int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u + 4u |^p dx= \int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u(x',x_n) + 4u(x',x_n) |^p dx' dx_n,$$
which is what you wrote. As you noted, $u$ is not defined for $x_n<0$, so this doesn't make sense. It is useful to write things out fully, instead of trying to use short notation.

As for Q3, using $$ |x+y|^p \le 2^{p-1}( |x|^p + |y|^p),$$
(this follows by the convexity of $t\mapsto t^p$ on $[0,\infty)$) you can split $\int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u(x',-x_n) + 4u(x',-x_n/2) |^p dx' dx_n$ into two types of integrals, times a constant depending on $p$:
One is
$$I_1=\int_{B^{-}} | u(x',-x_n)  |^p dx' dx_n = \int_{B^{+}} | u(x',y_n)  |^p dx' dy_n, $$
(by the obvious change of variables $B^- \to B^+$) and the other is
$$
I_2=\int_{B^{-}} | u(x',-x_n/2)  |^p dx' dx_n = 2\int_{V} | u(x',z_n)  |^p dx' dz_n ,$$
where $z_n = -x_n/2, dx_n = 2dz_n$ (as unsigned measures), and $$V:=\{ (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n/2) : x\in B^+\}.$$
Note that $V\subset B^+$; this means we can bound $I_2$ by
$$ I_2 \le 2\int_{B^+} | u(x)  |^p dx.$$
In total you should get for the $L^p$ norm,
$\| \overline u\|_{L^p(B)} \le C_p \|u\|_{L^p(B^+)}$ with $C_p=1+2^{p-1}(3+4\times 2).$ But what's important is that $C_p < \infty$, not the exact value.

This set $V$ is the correct one to use; note carefully it is different from $B^+\cap \{ x_n < r/2\}$ as in the screenshot.

For the derivatives, its the same calculation. The only thing is to be careful with chain rule if you want to compute the constant correctly: for $x\in B^-$,

$$ \partial_{x_n} \overline u(x) =  \partial_{x_n}(-3u(x',-x_n)+4u(x',-x_n/2)) = 3 (\partial_{x_n} u)(x',-x_n)-2 (\partial_{x_n} u)(x',-x_n/2)$$

The amusing fact that  $-3+4=1=3-2$, which you should have already seen when verifying the statements in the earlier part of the proof, is what makes the particular choice of "reflection" work.

Comment: I wasn't too sure of this property

$$\int_B | \overline{u} |^pdx = \int_{B\cap \{x_n = 0\}}  | \overline{u} |^p dx+ \int_{B^{+}} | u |^p dx+  \int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u(x',-x_n) + 4u(x',-x_n/2) |^p dx' dx_n.$$

I can't find this anywhere in analysis book. How do we know we can perform integration by parts like this? it is not countable additive. 

Also how do we know $B\cap \{ x_n = 0\}$has measure zero? Like with respect to what measure?

Comment: You don't really mean $u$ isn't defiend on the lower half right? Because we assumed $u\in C^\infty(\overline{U})$. It is just $\overline{u}$ is not defined as $u$ on the lower half.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the signed measure you talked about, but it doesn't seem like it has any major significat/impact on the estimation. We can do without by estimation by absolutel value right?

Comment: @Hawk the first property is merely additivity of the Lebesgue integral, together with the definition of $\bar u$ which is the extension of $u$. There is no integration by parts. I don’t know what signed measure you are talking about. I mean precisely that $u$ is not defined on the lower half. You are also correct that u is smooth on the closure of $U$. If you check the picture in Evans: the lower half of the ball is **outside** $U$. And, $\bar u$ **is** defined on the whole ball. It’s definition is given in your question.

Comment: Additionally it is easy to prove that any subset of $\{x_n=0\}$ has zero ($n$ dimensional) Lebesgue measure from first principles (ie considering the measure of covers by balls)

Comment: I just noticed I should not also define a set called $U$. I will change this notation now

Comment: 1. I shouldn't have called it Integration by parts. The three sets are not disjoint, so how is that additive? 

2. I was referring to the bracketed comment ("as unsigned measure)"

3. I see, that's what that black shade for. My 1st editor pdf isn't super clear because of age.

Comment: @Hawk 1. Oh. Well if you define $B^\pm$ As open sets ie $\{x_n > 0\}$ and $\{x_n < 0\}$ intersect $B$ Respectively then it is correct. But it’s not important to be careful here because the integral over a null set is zero. 2. Oh. What I mean is that I removed any sign from the Jacobian. I’m telling you the scaling factor from change of variables. That sentence is supposed to help you see the next line. If you don’t understand it then just do the change of variables your own way.

Comment: 1. I mean if they aren't open sets, we can't write that integral in the first place regardless if it the middle integral vanishes because the intersection is a null set. That was kinda my point, but this might be separate question 

2. Thats what I thought about the unsigned measure comment, it seemed inconsequential when we can estimate by absolute value in the first.

Comment: @Hawk The integral identity I wrote is still true even if it was closed sets, because integrals don’t care about null sets. I don’t know what integral you think I cannot write? Every integral in $$\int_B | \overline{u} |^pdx = \int_{B\cap \{x_n = 0\}}  | \overline{u} |^p dx+ \int_{B^{+}} | u |^p dx+  \int_{B^{-}} | {-3}u(x',-x_n) + 4u(x',-x_n/2) |^p dx' dx_n$$ makes sense

Comment: I'll just ask that property in another question as it seemed more like a "basic" question regarding the lesbegue integral. It is not something I have encountered or used before.

Comment: And I think I made another typo in my original post. But I think it was cleared up by your first point. The norm is just what Sebaton wrote below in this case.

Comment: @Hawk ok re first point. All I’m trying to say is since $0= \int_N f$ for a null set $N$, you can add it to any equation like $1=1+0$

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. For example, $u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n})$ is not defined if $x_{n}>0$.
2. 

$$\|\overline{u}\|_{W^{1,p}(B)}:=\left( \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 1} \int_{B}|D^{\alpha}\overline{u}|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}},$$
where $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^{n}$ is a multiindex and $|\alpha|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}$ is its norm. If you expand this, you obtain
$$\|\overline{u}\|_{W^{1,p}(B)}=\left( \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 1} \int_{B}|D^{\alpha}\overline{u}|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\left(\int_{B}|\overline{u}|^{p}dx+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{B}|\overline{u}_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$
Also
$$\int_{B}|\overline{u}|^{p}dx=\int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx+\int_{B^{-}}|-3u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n})+4u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n}/2)|^{p}dx. $$
The integral over $\{x_{n}=0\}$ vanishes because this set has Lebesgue measure zero.

3. Their stimations do not have sense because $u(\ldots,-x_{n}/2)$ is only defined for $B^{+}$, not for the whole ball.

Finally, let me prove that $\|\overline{u}\|_{W^{1,p}(B)} \leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B^{+})}$.
Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_{B}|\overline{u}|^{p}dx &=\int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx+\int_{B^{-}}|-3u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n})+4u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n}/2)|^{p}dx \\
&\leq \int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx+3\int_{B^{-}}|u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n})|^{p}dx+4\int_{B^{-}}u(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1},-x_{n}/2)|^{p}dx \\
&=\int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx+3\int_{B^{+}}|u(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n-1},y_{n})|^{p}dy+2\int_{B^{+}}u(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n-1},y_{n})|^{p}dy, \\
&=6\int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx.
\end{align*}
where in the penultimate inequality I used the substitutions $(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n})=(x_{1},\ldots,-x_{n})$ and $(y_{1},\ldots,y_{n})=(x_{1},\ldots,-x_{n}/2)$, respectively. Also,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{B}|\overline{u}_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx=&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx+\int_{B^{-}}|(-3u(\ldots,-x_{n})+4u(\ldots,-x_{n}/2))_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx\right) \\
&+\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{n}}|^{p}dx+\int_{B^{-}}|3u_{x_{n}}(\ldots,-x_{n})-2u(\ldots,-x_{n}/2)|^{p}dx \\
\leq &\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx+3\int_{B^{-}}|u_{x_{i}}(\ldots,-x_{n})|^{p}dx+4\int_{B^{-}}|u_{x_{i}}(\ldots,-x_{n}/2)|^{p}dx\right) \\
&+\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{n}}|^{p}dx+3\int_{B^{-}}|u_{x_{n}}(\ldots,-x_{n})|^{p}dx+2\int_{B^{-}}|u(\ldots,-x_{n}/2)|^{p}dx \\
=&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx+3\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx+2\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx\right) \\
&+\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{n}}|^{p}dx+3\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{n}}|^{p}dx+\int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx \\
=&6 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx,
\end{align*}
where I  used the same substitutions as before.
Finally
\begin{align*}
\|\overline{u}\|_{W^{1,p}(B)} &=\left(\int_{B}|\overline{u}|^{p}dx+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{B}|\overline{u}_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
& \leq 6^{1/p}\left(\int_{B^{+}}|u|^{p}dx+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{B^{+}}|u_{x_{i}}|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
&=6^{1/p} \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(B^{+})}.
\end{align*}